# Set scrollbar height different to height of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to set a div's, for example, scrollbar height to a height that is smaller than the div's height?

E.G. a `<div>` with `height` set to `400px` and `overflow-y:scroll`. Then set the scrollbar's `height` to `300px` ? So that there is a gap between the bottom of the scrollbar and the bottom of the `<div>`.

Is this possible with CSS only? If not, then can it be achieved simply with some JS?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using (works in Webkit browsers only)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-clip: content-box;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: But that's for webkit browser only. Your answer should at least mention it imho